# Adapting Common Lisp "pushnew" to return success/failure

Tags: macros, common-lisp, anonymous-function

The Common Lisp macro `pushnew` returns the (possibly updated) place list given as an argument. It appears that if you want to know whether a given item was actually pushed or not, you would need to compare the before and after place list to see if it had changed. But this is too inefficient for my use, since it would involve repeatedly comparing two lists of complex structure objects for equivalence.

Another alternative that might work is to use the :test argument to `pushnew` to record if the item has been found yet, as the list elements are scanned. If the item is found, T can be returned as a second multiple value, otherwise NIL. The following macro tries to do this:

```
(defmacro pushnew+p (item place &key test (key #'identity) &aux old?)
  "Same as pushnew, but also returns whether item was pushed."
  `(values (pushnew ,item ,place
                    :test (lambda (item element)
                            (if ,test
                              (setf old? (funcall ,test item element))
                              (setf old? (eql item element))))
                    :key ,key)
           (not old?)))
```

It seems to work OK since

```
(defparameter x '(1 2 3))

(pushnew+p 0 x) -> (0 1 2 3), T

(pushnew+p 2 x) -> (0 1 2 3), NIL

(defparameter y '((1) (2) (3)))

(pushnew+p '(0) y :test #'equal) -> ((0) (1) (2) (3)), T

(pushnew+p '(2) y :test #'equal) -> ((0) (1) (2) (3)), NIL
```

However, I'm not sure about how the :test argument works, and the Hyperspec entry for `pushnew` does not explicitly say. Is it guaranteed that the testing of list elements stops as soon as the test returns T, as is desired? (Alternately for `remove`, the testing should continue on to the end of the sequence.) If testing does continue to the end, would a `return-from` be the best way to terminate early?

Another problem is that the anonymous lambda body repeatedly checks for a given `,test` argument for each element. Can this be moved outside the lambda? Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the better way is to check whether the new element is, in fact, *prepended* as specified by [`pushnew`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_pshnew.htm):

```
(unless (eq item (car place))
  (pushnew item place ...)
  (when (eq item (car place))
    ;; not found, prepended
    ))
```

Note that even if you pass `:test` to `pushnew`, you still use `eq` in `unless` and `when`.

PS. Please note the corner case mentioned in a comment by @coredump.

Comment: Small corner case: If ITEM is NIL and PLACE is empty, the result is not (NIL) as expected. The first test could be `(unless (and place (eq item (car place))) ...)` for example.

Comment: Must be nice to just "see" like an expert.